# MySQL Foreign Key Error 1005 errno 150 (table engine, fields types, lengths and indexations are ok)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I know there are a LOT of similar questions about this error (FOREIGN KEY fail at table creation or update). I've already checked :

- both tables are all InnoDb
- all fields are indexed (or PKs, so.. indexed), int and length 10

But it still doesn't work... Now, I just hope that somewone will have a look on my SQL code and tell me if something is wrong :(

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `hotels`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `hotels`;
CREATE TABLE `hotels` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  -- other fields
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `hotelsearch_query`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `hotelsearch_query`;
CREATE TABLE `hotelsearch_query` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  -- other fields
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `hotelsearch_result`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `hotelsearch_result`;
CREATE TABLE `hotelsearch_result` (
  `query_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `hotel_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  -- other fields
  PRIMARY KEY (`query_id`,`hotel_id`),
  KEY `IDX_QUERY` (`query_id`),
  KEY `IDX_HOTEL` (`hotel_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`query_id`) REFERENCES `hotelsearch_query`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (`hotel_id`) REFERENCES `hotels`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

When I remove the 2 lines about foreign keys, everything works well. When i try both, or one by one, I also have the error.

Please help me !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data types of the columns and the references must be the same. Change the definition like this and it will work:

```
CREATE TABLE `hotelsearch_result` (
  `query_id` int(10)  NOT NULL,
  `hotel_id` int(10)  NOT NULL,
  ...
```

Your ids where of type `int unsigned` and the references of type `int`

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46ac5)

Comment: oh my.......
Thanks a lot... I checked via Navicat, and not in the code itself. What a shame...
Thanks !